# How can I find the same objects between two arrays

Tags: arrays, powershell, compare

Consider the following arrays:

```
$users = 'igor', 'max', 'andrew'
$server_admins = 'john', 'andrew', 'li', 'alex'
```

I need an alert if any member of `$users` is in `$server_admins`
In example above it will be true because of 'andrew' from `$users`

Should I use `Compare-object`? Or not ? If yes - how ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Several correct answers for this. Some are simpler and cleaner than others. Whatever works best with your data.

```
$users = 'igor','max','andrew'
$server_admins = 'john','andrew','li','alex'

# Using Compare-Object
Compare-Object $users -DifferenceObject $server_admins -IncludeEqual | Where sideindicator -eq "==" | Select-Object -ExpandProperty InputObject

# Using -contains and where
$users | Where-Object{$server_admins -contains $_}
```

Pipe either of those into `Foreach-Object` and alert away. Likely I would choose the latter options as it is more terse and just as easy to understand.

Answer (score 2):

You could just do something using `-in` or `-contains`, example:

```
$users = 'igor','max','andrew'
$server_admins = 'john','andrew','li','alex'

$users | % {
    if($_ -in $server_admins)
    {
        'alert'
    }
}
```

Comment: Any way to use that it in filter? So, TRUE if any user is in $server_admins array?


filter FilterDN 
{ 
        if (here...)) 
        { 
           # if any user is in server admin,then..
        }  
}

Get-QADUser .... | FilterDN

Comment: Not sure what you mean, maybe something like `$users | ? {$_ -in $server_admins}`?

Comment: Hmm, no multiline. I mean to use it in IF expression... So, If (any user in server group) {.... }

Answer (score 0):

To have a test with a single if command:

```
$users = 'igor','max','andrew'
$server_admins = 'john','andrew','li','alex'
If ( @($users | Where-Object{$server_admins -contains $_ }).Length){"yes"}
```